# Finding a template for Mathematical Finance journal

Tags: formatting, templates, journal

I am trying to find *or* create a LaTeX template that is the same as the one in this article: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/mafi.12004/epdf. Specifically, I am trying to create the same definition, theorem, abstract, keywords, header, and section style. From what I see, the section style looks very much like `amsart` but the title, author, header, and footnotes style on the title page doesn't look right when I use `amsart`.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can ask the author what is his setup to create this document

Comment: @RomainPicot I think the journal format it themselves, but I just want to make it similar to that format before submitting it to the journal. Also, the journal doesn't provide any information about its template on their website.

Comment: From http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1111/%28ISSN%291467-9965/homepage/ForAuthors.html I'd say they take 'classical' manuscript submissions, most probably in word processor format.

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, I've seen that. From what I understand, they just want the authors to follow some certain formats for specific things in the manuscript (e.g., double-spacing, etc.). However, on top of those specified formats, the authors are allowed to do any formatting they wish. At least, that is what I understand.

Comment: Is there any news here?